# Android HttpGet request

Tags: android

i tried to GET some json string from a server but I receive this error when I want to connect to server:

> 10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stampp/com.example.stampp.UI.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:848)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:674)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:511)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:489)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at com.example.stampp.Services.ConfigurateAPI.ConnectApi.postAuthorization(ConnectApi.java:51)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at com.example.stampp.UI.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
>   10-07 10:57:47.410: E/AndroidRuntime(11050):    ... 11 more

This is my code:

```
public void getAuthorization(String password, String user) {
    String responseString="empty response from api";
    String userPassword = user+":"+password;
    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(_url);

        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            httpResponse.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    }catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can someone to help me?

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException. Google it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **Android 3.0** you cannot use a network connection on the **main thread**. You better create an `AsynTask` with `doInBackground` to execute you `httpget`.

Answer (score 0):

Use some AsyncTask to do it. See [this](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/http/android-how-to-send-http-get-request-to-servlet-using-apache-http-client/) basic example.